# Object reference not set to an instance of an object; I tried fixing it

Tags: visual-studio

I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I attempt to create a new project, and when I click OK and then try to create a new class it fails to. I found that it happens to people who installed RC versions of Visual Studio, which I did (Visual Studio 2019 RC). I tried reinstalling, uninstalling the Visual Studio Installer, Visual Studios etc.

It doesn't work in VS 2017 nor VS 2019.

How do I fix it?

[image: ActivityLog.xml Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are invalid paths in enviromnent variables, attempting to reinstall Visual Studio Installer & Visual Studio with removing these enviromnent variables.

EDIT: It worked